# Facebook API publish_pages permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

The company I work for has a Facebook integration which I am currently trying to fix for them.

When the request to connect the account to Facebook the code sends
['publish_pages', 'manage_pages']
for the permissions, When I am logged into my profile (Admin of the app) on the auth screen Facebook shows, I get to pick both of the permissions in check boxes, If I then log out and login to a different Facebook account (Standard account with 1 page) and try the process again I only get an option for manage_pages. Which then means we cant post to the page...

Could anyone shred some light on this?. The app has "Approved: publish_pages, manage_pages" under the verification section.

To give a little more context to the situation it is an advertising company that sends out marketing campaigns via various communication methods and it has an option to post to a facebook page.

Comment: Can you check what role that other account has on the page? (Page settings -> Page Roles)

Comment: Showing as "Admin"

Comment: Could that account maybe have declined the permission for this app before? Try and remove the app completely from the user’s settings, and see if trying to login again after changes anything.

Comment: Ive just noticed that i dont have "Individual verification" on the app, Although the app is approved. Ill await that to be verified and try again, Not sure why its all of a sudden requested individual verification